# PHP LDAP debug output in PHP script

Tags: php, debugging, ldap

I want to fetch debug information of an ldap connection in a PHP script (Windows Environment). To activate the debug output you have to use ldap_set_option calling ldap_connect:

```
ldap_set_option(NULL, LDAP_OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL, 7);
```

And it is necessary to run the from command line. Otherwise you wont get the debug output. In a reqeust this debug output is not shown.

```
<?php

// Set the ldap server
$ldapurl = "foo.bar";

// Set debugging
ldap_set_option(NULL, LDAP_OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL, 7);

// connect to ldap server
$ldapconn = ldap_connect($ldapurl) or die ("Couldn't connect"); 

// binding to ldap server
$ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldapuser, $ldappass);

?>
```

The result of the command-line:

```
C:\>C:\Apache\php\php-cgi.exe -f C:\Apache\htdocs\ldap_debug.php
    ldap_url_parse_ext(ldap://localhost/)
    ldap_init: trying c:\openldap\sysconf\ldap.conf
    ldap_init: HOME env is NULL
    ldap_init: trying ldaprc
    ldap_init: LDAPCONF env is NULL
    ldap_init: LDAPRC env is NULL
    ldap_create
    ldap_bind_s
    ldap_simple_bind_s
    ldap_sasl_bind_s
    ldap_sasl_bind
    ldap_send_initial_request
    ldap_new_connection 1 1 0
    ldap_int_open_connection
    ldap_connect_to_host: TCP foo.bar:389
    ldap_new_socket: 776
    ldap_prepare_socket: 776
    ldap_connect_to_host: Trying 192.168.42.20:389
    ldap_pvt_connect: fd: 776 tm: -1 async: 0
    ldap_open_defconn: successful
    ldap_send_server_request
    ldap_result ld 091BAC10 msgid 1
    wait4msg ld 091BAC10 msgid 1 (infinite timeout)
    wait4msg continue ld 091BAC10 msgid 1 all 1
    ** ld 091BAC10 Connections:
    * host: foo.bar  port: 389  (default)
      refcnt: 2  status: Connected
      last used: Mon Dec 15 09:16:49 2014


    ** ld 091BAC10 Outstanding Requests:
     * msgid 1,  origid 1, status InProgress
       outstanding referrals 0, parent count 0
      ld 091BAC10 request count 1 (abandoned 0)
    ** ld 091BAC10 Response Queue:
       Empty
      ld 091BAC10 response count 0
    ldap_chkResponseList ld 091BAC10 msgid 1 all 1
    ldap_chkResponseList returns ld 091BAC10 NULL
    ldap_int_select
    read1msg: ld 091BAC10 msgid 1 all 1
    read1msg: ld 091BAC10 msgid 1 message type bind
    read1msg: ld 091BAC10 0 new referrals
    read1msg:  mark request completed, ld 091BAC10 msgid 1
    request done: ld 091BAC10 msgid 1
    res_errno: 0, res_error: <>, res_matched: <>
    ldap_free_request (origid 1, msgid 1)
    ldap_parse_result
    ldap_msgfree
    ldap_free_connection 1 1
    ldap_send_unbind
    ldap_free_connection: actually freed
```

Now I want to do this in a request (`http://localhost/ldap_debug.php?cmd`):

```
<?php

if (isset($_REQUEST['cmd']))
{
    $aOutput = array();
    $sCmdLine = "C:\\Apache\\php\\php-cgi.exe -f ".__FILE__;
    exec($sCmdLine, $aOutput);
    print_r($aOutput);
    exit;
}

// Set the ldap server
$ldapurl = "foo.bar";

// Set debugging
ldap_set_option(NULL, LDAP_OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL, 7);

// connect to ldap server
$ldapconn = ldap_connect($ldapurl) or die ("Couldn't connect"); 

// binding to ldap server
$ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn, $ldapuser, $ldappass);

?>
```

But the result array is $aOutput is empty. Any hints?

Comment: In `$sCmdLine` check your backslashes I think they should be escaped. And also is better to use `shell_exec` instead of `exec` in my opinion.

Comment: You're right, the backslashes should be escaped. But it also worked with unescaped backslashes. But I changed this with no effect. `shell_exec` has the same result on this like `exec`. Referring to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7093860/php-shell-exec-vs-exec I cannot tell if shell_exec is the better way to do this.

Comment: I guess the debug output is not really written to stdout: If I try this: `C:\Apache\php\php-cgi.exe -f C:\Apache\htdocs\ldap_debug.php >> ldap.log` the file only contain other output than the debug output

Comment: For Linux, see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/21857617/2908724.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Redirect Windows cmd stdout and stderr to a single file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420965/redirect-stdout-and-stderr-to-a-single-file) I can answer my own question. The trick is to redirect stderr to stdout:

```
$sCmdLine = "C:\\Apache\\php\\php-cgi.exe -f ".__FILE__." 2>&1";
```