# How to determine what version tls/ssl security protocol is connecting to LDAP (PHP)?

Tags: php, ssl, openldap, tls1.2, tls1.1

I am using the openLDAP library. How do I determine what security protocol type and version my server is using to connect to the AD server?

```
ldap_connect("ldaps://server:636");
```

I understand for websites, I can easily see the type and version by looking at the properties from the browsers..

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21857617/how-to-view-stderr-of-phps-ldap-functions-with-ldap-opt-debug-level-7-from), have a look at [ldap_set_option](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.ldap-set-option.php) which comes with a bunch of options, and can enable the debugging with

```
ldap_set_option(NULL, LDAP_OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL, 7);
```